# Blazor WebAssembly pass enum as parameter to component

Tags: asp.net-core, enums, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating a Blazor WebAssembly app, I have an enum I'd like to pass as parameter to my Blazor component like this

```
public enum EMenu
{
    Menu1 = 1,
    Menu2 = 2,
    Menu3 = 3,
}

[Parameter] public EMenu Id { get; set; }

<NavMenu id="menu1" />
```

The `EMenu` is my enum, `Id` is my parameter on my `NavMenu` component. But it errors out with `Specified cast is not valid` message.

I googled and saw this GitHub issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19139 and according to it the following should work when you prefix the enum value with your enum name

```
<NavMenu id="EMenu.Menu1" />
```

But it did not work for me, same error. Could someone help point out what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this parameter property is defined on your NavMenu component

```
[Parameter] public EMenu Id { get; set; }
```

Then you instantiate the NavMenu component like this:

```
<NavMenu Id="EMenu.Menu1"/>
```

`Id` instead of `id` as you did... `Id` is a component parameter that starts with capital letter.

Your enum class should be residing in the root folder of your application.